# Logic in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

Some one can help me how to write a logic in batch file as describes below,

I have to write a logic in batch file to get latest version of file from the given directory. List latest version of zip file in popup, so that user can select the required version of zip file from the popup and proceed further.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: from the given directory i can able to download the zip file but i dint know how to list the file based on the version.

Comment: Can you post 1) what the version looks like (eg 1, 2 1.00.220) and 2) what the filenames look like.  By popup, do you mean a hta popup?